# Brackets extensions stopped working

Tags: text-editor, adobe-brackets

I'm using a number of extensions in Brackets like JSHint and Less autocompile, which were stopped working for a while. Not sure why exactly. Tried to reload, reopen w/o extensions, reinstall extensions but nothing seems to resolve the problem.

As an example, a grey circle showing up in the bottom right corner instead of the usual icons of JSHint:

[image]

Using Brackets version 1.9 with Less AutoCompile v.1.1.10 and JSHint v2.2.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. `linting.enabled` was set to false in brackets.json for some reason.